# Computing weighted standard deviation using lowess mean values

Tags: standard-deviation, kernel-smoothing, smoothing, loess

I have two questions:

**First question:**

I want to compute the weighted standard deviation with tri-cubic kernel. I am using lowess function in R to compute the weighted mean using tri-cubic kernel. But unfortunately the lowess function in R does not give the std (or I am not aware of it).
My question is, if I use

1. the mean values computed by R,
2. compute the weight (using tri-cubic kernel) for each point with an span (alpha) of 0.01
3. and put every thing in the formula [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/how-do-i-calculate-a-weighted-standard-deviation-in-excel),

Is the computed std correct or not? (for example, are the weights that I have computed exactly the same as the ones used by lowess to compute the mean?)

**Second question:**

why the lowess values computed by R are so different with the ones computed in the smooth function in MATLAB?

Comment: Can you share a little bit about your data, maybe a snippet and some summary stats, and can you share some of the Matlab code that you used?